# unable to form connection with Jenkins build slave

Tags: jenkins

I've created a Jenkins build slave running on Ubuntu and my master runs on windows, when I attempt to connect to the slave I get:

```
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused: connect".
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to ubuntu-vbox:22
```

The Ubuntu firewall is disabled, nothing is using port 22 on the Ubuntu vm, I can ping the Ubuntu server and the ssh plugin is installed. AFAIK I should need to do anything with ssh keys.

Can someone point me in the correct direction for resolving this.

Comment: Can you show your slave configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was, my Ubuntu vm did not have the open ssh server installer, I am shame faced for accepting points for marking my own question as answered, however this is the answer nonetheless.